# Find the combination algorithm for 16 digit numbers

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Find the combination algorithm for numbers that will be generated.
And the numbers are:

```
0535 8549 9933 3564
0500 7197 6709 9534
0531 3170 7802 8731
```

The numbers are not generated randomly.
The numbers always start with 05.

Comment: I don't understand the problem at all. You have an algorithm that spits out sequences of 16 digits, and we have to figure out what the algorithm is?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: Only three numbers given? This might be too broad.

Comment: @Gunarves In that case, if there really is no randomness, then the algorithm should output the same 16 digit sequence every time. How is it possible that there are three? Does the algorithm output an infinite sequence of 16-digit words?

Comment: ...or is it that in fact the algorithm doesn't *generate* 16-digit words, it *reads* them, and either accepts or rejects them according to some rule?